# Python/Sympy find eigenvalues with matrix not identity

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I have two sympy matrices `M` and `K`. How can I find the values `w`such that `det(K - w*M) = 0`?

In sympy [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html), there is only `M.eigenvals` to find `lamda` such that `det(A-lamda*I) = 0`

**PS:** Solving the problem `det(K - w*M) = 0` is the same of solving the problem `det(M^{-1} * K - w * I) = 0`, but computing the inverse of `M` can be expensive.

Comment: This will probably depend on the size of the matrix and the cost of the conversion but how about [using lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to convert to numpy and then use [eigvals](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvals.html) ?

Comment: My test case matrix are 4x4, but it can be much larger like 20x20. But I will use your tip to convert to numpy's array at frist and then calculate the eigvals. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Unless we are talking thousands and thousands of values, the cost of computing the conversion to numpy and then the eigenvalues should be negligible